# Marshmallow hooks on schema inheritance

Tags: python, marshmallow

How can we chain `Marshmallow` hooks when you use schema inheritance?

Suppose the following "dumb" example:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load


class PersonSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()

    @post_load
    def post_load(self, data, **_):
        data["name"] = data["name"].capitalize()
        return data


class EmployeeSchema(PersonSchema):
    title = fields.Str()

    @post_load
    def post_load(self, data, **_):
        data["title"] = data["title"].upper()
        return data

EmployeeSchema().load({"name": "john", "title": "ceo"})
# {"name": "john", "title": "CEO"}
```

In this example, only the subclassed hook was triggered. How do you make the parent hook trigger as well on deserialization, in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is using different method names for the same hook:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load


class PersonSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()

    @post_load
    def person_post_load(self, data, **_):
        data["name"] = data["name"].capitalize()
        return data


class EmployeeSchema(PersonSchema):
    title = fields.Str()

    @post_load
    def employee_post_load(self, data, **_):
        data["title"] = data["title"].upper()
        return data

EmployeeSchema().load({"name": "john", "title": "ceo"})
# {"name": "John", "title": "CEO"}
```

Now each hook gets called sequentially.

Comment: What if `EmployeeSchema` doesn't 
 have any `@post_load` decorators? So when we try to `load` then I guess **title** won't be available